# How to use reduce on object

Tags: javascript, object, reduce

I'm trying to loop a object using reduce to generate a html list

```js
const dropdownTemplate = (data) => {
 console.log(data);  // always empty
 return `
  <li class="dropdown__item" data-value="${data.value}"><span class="dropdown__itemCode">${data.code}</span> <span class="dropdown__itemText">${data.name}</span></li>
 `;
};

const data_obj = JSON.parse('[ { "type": "hotel", "value": 25, "name":"Hotel name", "code": "sn", "lat" : "1.3", "long" : "1.33" } ]');
const fetched_items = data_obj.reduce((item, generated) => {
 generated += dropdownTemplate(item);
 return generated;
}, '');
console.log(fetched_items); // allways filled with undefined values
```

But can't understand why the item is always empty (so it generates the list with undefined values),

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you inverted `item` and `generated`.

`generated` is the element keeped from one loop to another; and `item` the element of the array treated in the actual loop.

```js
const dataObj = JSON.parse('[ { "value": 25, "name":"Hotel name", "code": "sn"  }, { "value": 30, "name2":"Hotel name2", "code": "sn2" } ]');

const dropdownTemplate = data => `<li class="dropdown__item" data-value="${data.value}"><span class="dropdown__itemCode">${data.code}</span> <span class="dropdown__itemText">${data.name}</span></li>\n\n`;

const fetchedItems = dataObj.reduce((tmp, x) => `${tmp}${dropdownTemplate(x)}`, '');

console.log(fetchedItems);
```

Comment: There's also no need to store back to the parameter, just: `return generated + dropdownTemplate(item);`. We can also use the concise form: `const fetched_items = data_obj.reduce((generated, item) => generated + dropdownTemplate(item), '');`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Right, I didn't even though about refactoring it ^^'

Comment: Ha! You went a step further with a template literal! :-)

Answer (score -2):

Ideally you should use map for this kind of scenarios.

> Reduce params are like this (aggregate, item) => {}

```
const dropdownTemplate = (data) => {
return `
    <li class="dropdown__item" data-value="${data.value}">
    <span class="dropdown__itemCode">${data.code}</span> <span class="dropdown__itemText">${data.name}</span>
    </li>`;
 };

const data_obj = JSON.parse('[ { "type": "hotel", "value": 25, "name":"Hotel 
name", "code": "sn", "lat" : "1.3", "long" : "1.33" } ]');

const fetched_items = data_obj.reduce((combinedHtml, item) => {
   combinedHtml += dropdownTemplate(item);
   return combinedHtml;
}, '');

console.log(fetched_items);
```